# how can i delete git from $PATH or change path so that it no longer contains it (macOS)

Tags: bash, git, terminal

I have recently updated git and it has changed my path to

/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/matthew/git
I try to use composer and execute files and I get the error

env: php: No such file or directory.
when

I reset the path back to

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
everything works fine and composer loads but the only thing is it automatically sets the path back to /usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/matthew/git in a matter of seconds after me doing what I need to do.

i thought the path would stay and go back to the original one i reset it to but it auto reverts back to the git one
Is there any way i can fix this without having to reinstall the operating system? and keep the path as PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" i have been stuck on this for two days i just want rid of git

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=change+PATH

Answer (score 0):

you should update your `.bash_profile` file

you can check [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) for futher details

Answer (score 0):

@funkyjelly thanks but this was still no good ended up having to reinstall the operating system and install git via home brew and the problem with the path was solved